# How to insert a scroll bar to a dev class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to add a scroll bar to the drop-down list of my code.It is actually a cart which shows the items in the cart when I click on the cart. I want to put a scroll bar to it to go down and see the items on it as the drop down box has a fixed size.

The code I used for the cart is:

```
<ul id="cart-dropdown" class="box-dropdown parent-arrow">
<li>
<div class="box-wrapper parent-border">
<p>Recently added item(s)</p>
<table class="cart-table">
<tr>
<td><img src="img/products/sample1.jpg" alt="product"></td>
<td>
<h6>Lorem ipsum dolor</h6>
<p>Product code PSBJ3</p>
</td>
<td>
<span class="quantity"><span class="light">1 x</span> $79.00</span>
<a href="#" class="parent-color">Remove</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="img/products/sample1.jpg" alt="product"></td>
<td>
<h6>Lorem ipsum dolor</h6>
<p>Product code PSBJ3</p>
</td>
<td>
<span class="quantity"><span class="light">1 x</span> $79.00</span>
<a href="#" class="parent-color">Remove</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="img/products/sample1.jpg" alt="product"></td>
<td>
<h6>Lorem ipsum dolor</h6>
<p>Product code PSBJ3</p>
</td>
<td>
<span class="quantity"><span class="light">1 x</span> $79.00</span>
 <a href="#" class="parent-color">Remove</a>
 </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<br class="clearfix">
 </div>                                            
<div class="footer">
<table class="checkout-table pull-right">
<tr>
<td class="align-right">Tax:</td>
 <td>$0.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="align-right">Discount:</td>
 <td>$37.00</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class="align-right"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
<td><strong class="parent-color">$999.00</strong></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="box-wrapper no-border">
<a class="button pull-right parent-background" href="#">Checkout</a>
<a class="button pull-right" href="order_info.html">View Cart</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wants something like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub0qkgxy/)

```
#cart-dropdown { height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `overflow:scroll` to your element's CSS?

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this